# FOSUserBundle - override profile/edit view

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle 2.0 and Symfony 2.8 and I want to place some more HTML code inside `profile/edit` view. Right know there's only the autogenerated form.

I've succesfully created a view that overrides profile/show and registration form, but it does not work for profile/edit.

I have copied `edit_content.html.twig` file into location:
`app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Profile` but symfony still reads the original file: 
`vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views/Profile/edit_content.html.twig`.

Why is that?

**app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Profile/edit_content.html.twig**:

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'action': path('fos_user_profile_edit'), 'attr': { 'class': 'fos_user_profile_edit' } }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="{{ 'profile.edit.submit'|trans }}" />
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Thank you

Comment: did you clear the cache? alos, what i use in my project is put the code inside 
`{% block fos_user_content %}..
{% endblock fos_user_content %}` blocks

Comment: You're right - clearing the cache helped ;)

I've also overridden layout.html.twig - it's the place where I put the `{% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}` block.

Comment: I am happy @Torpedr